# golden-layout-2 error: Error: Component type not registered and BindComponentEvent handler not assigned

Tags: angular, typescript, golden-layout

I am trying to migrate an old golden-layout implementation in an Angular 16 application, to golden-layout-2. The previous implementation worked as expected.

The code to initialise the layout is like this:

```
// create the layout
this.goldenLayout = new GoldenLayout(this.el.nativeElement);

// add golden-layout event handlers
this.registerGoldenLayoutEventListeners();

// register all golden-layout components
this.glService.initialize(this.goldenLayout, this);
  
// Initialize the layout
const layoutConfig = LayoutConfig.fromResolved(this.goldenLayout.layoutConfig);
layoutConfig.root = layout.root;
this.goldenLayout.loadLayout(layoutConfig);
```

The `initialize` function above is responsible for registering the components, it looks like this:

```
this.config.components.forEach((componentConfig: ComponentConfiguration) => {
    const componentInitCallback = componentInitCallbackFactory.createComponentInitCallback(componentConfig.component);

    goldenLayout.registerComponentFactoryFunction(componentConfig.componentType.toString(), componentInitCallback, false);
});
```

The `createComponentInitCallback` function basically creates the inner Angular component.

There are no errors in the editor, it all looks like it *should* work, but is giving the error:

> Error: Component type not registered and BindComponentEvent handler not assigned

It seems like the `registerComponentFactoryFunction` should be registering the components, but I guess from the error message it is not for some reason..? Also I am not sure why it is complaining about `BindComponentEvent handler not assigned` - bindComponentEvent handler is supposedly optional and I assumed it would not be required for "Embedding via Registration" (known as "classic registration", as described here: https://golden-layout.github.io/golden-layout/binding-components/)

Can someone provide some guidance? What am I missing?

**Edit**

As requested, here is a copy of the current config:

```
WidgetGoldenLayoutConfig = {
    dimensions: {
        dragProxyHeight: 300,
        dragProxyWidth: 300,
    },
    settings: {
        showPopoutIcon: false,
    },
    content: [
        {
            componentName: null,
            componentState: undefined,
            height: null,
            id: null,
            isClosable: true,
            title: null,
            type: 'column',
            width: null,
            content: [
                {
                    componentName: null,
                    componentState: undefined,
                    height: null,
                    id: 'bfa378a3-2b9f-455d-b574-d0114daf3fa2',
                    isClosable: true,
                    title: null,
                    type: 'stack',
                    width: null,
                    content: [
                        componentName: 'golden-layout-widget',
                        componentType: 'golden-layout-widget',
                        componentState: {},
                        content: [],
                        height: null,
                        id: null,
                        isClosable: true,
                        title: 'My widget',
                        type: 'component',
                        width: null,
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

**Edit 2**

I checked why we were using toString() - it was basically to fix type issues in VSCode - it was highlighting `componentType` and giving error "Argument of type 'JsonValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number is not assignable to type 'string'".

So toString() was used to keep VSCode happy. The actual value of componentType (and previously componentName) are definitely string values.

Nevertheless, the changes I made since Daniel G's answer below have not made a difference, I still see the same error.

I am also seeing a second error after the first:

> Cannot access rootItem before init

Again, this error is originating deep within golden-layout source, I have no idea why it occurs

**Edit 3**

Daniel G was right, problem was with `componentType` - in some cases this property was missing, so I ensured it existed (and was a string) for all cases, and error has gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see your config, but I find it interesting that your first parameter in the call to `registerComponentFactoryFunction` is *componentConfig.componentType.**toString()***.  According to the documentation the  *componentType* property of *ComponetItemConfig* must be of type *string* if it is registered with *registerComponentFactoryFunction*.

Is calling `toString()` your way of converting a *JsonValue* to a *string* because it is initially some other type?  If so, this may be way the registration is not found. Internally, components registered with classic methods are added to a map object so when they are retrieved the value in *componentTypeName* must be exactly the same as how it was registered.

In your config, I would make sure **all** the assignments to the *componentType* property are of *string* type and not some other type.

Comment: @DanielGimenz Thanks, I will check it. Yes I did find that I had to call `toString()` for the JsonValue. I've placed a partial copy of the config in the answer (in the app, there are multiple stacks containing components, but for brevity I just included one above). And actually, I can see the config is missing the `componentType` property somehow, so probably this is related also